# Zend studio/- framework not installed properly?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

(mind you: I'm a complete noob regarding zend framework. I've been using CodeIgniter and Zend Studio for quite some time now but felt the need to "expand", so to say.)

Using the Studios built in ZF generator I made myself a fresh ZF 1.11 install on my localhost. However, when I tried to access my newly made index page, I cannot see a thing. I fear that Studio has not installed the proper files for my Framework appilcation, seeing that the `require_once 'Zend/Application.php';` line requires it to load a non-existing file.

Could anyone give a hand perhaps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend library path is not correctly configured in php.ini file.
Configure the above stated file and also put the zf.bat or zf.sh according to your working platform in the path directory of the system.

Then, configure your httpd.conf file and configure the virtual host as follows (On linux Platform).

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride All    
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@server.om.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName www.om.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Along with that

mod_rewrite should be enabled in your httpd.conf file of Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some more details about your installation.  I use Zend all day but I dont use Zend Studio zf generator,  so I dont know how it has set you up.

What OS are you running and whats your apache server setup?  (Zend Community Server, wamp, mamp)

Have you setup added your domain name to the host file? 127.0.0.1  dev.mydomain

Is your VHOST pointing to the public directory?

Do you have an .htaccess file inside your public folder.

I am thinking at the very least if it is set up correctly you should see the blue and green Zend Framework output in your Index Controller view Script.

Comment: I second the above. Two most common issues on initial creation are missing library/Zend library and missing .htaccess (been there done that :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the paths are correct in /public/index.php.
Its quite possible your zend library is not in /library and thus you must ajust your paths accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Download ZF from its website and copy the folder "Zend" inside your application library folder and then check again . Also open index.php inside your public folder and paste this code on top

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));
```